# docker image for php is not working on browser for windows 10

Tags: php, apache, docker

I just started to learn docker and tried to create a php image with apache using docker file. As per my understanding I am able to create image using the docker file and after building image I tried to run that image in the form of container and it looks fine to me but when I tried to run that on the browser using "172.17.0.2" IP address its showing The connection was reset issue and i tried a lot but not able to resolve this issue. I am attaching few images for to clearly mention my issue.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

and the screen of windows pwershell showing

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>
> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message                     [Sat Oct 13 17:42:22.816118 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations                                              [Sat Oct 13 17:42:22.817371 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's your actual `docker run` command?  What's the actual URL you're trying to reach?  Are you using Docker Toolbox?  Do you know about the `docker run -p` option?

Comment: I am using docker run my-php-app, where my-php-app is my image name. I tried to reach  http://172.17.0.2. No I am not using docker toolbox as windows 10 supports docker CE which runs on hyper-v. Also I tried to edit my windows host file by adding 172.17.0.2 dockerphp.example.com and tried to reach http://dockerphp.example.com but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue now, there were two problems:
(1) I was trying to reach an incorrect IP the correct was 127.0.0.1
(2) I wasn't running windows power shell as admin to run docker commands.

One more thing if anyone still faces the same issue than make sure you configured to access shared drive for docker containers through docker interface.

Answer (score 0):

I also worked through the https://hub.docker.com/_/php apache example. I solved the issue by clarifying ownership of the php sources by adding a third line to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```